# Is this the proper way to use callbacks in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, callback

While doing iOS development I have always used the delegate pattern to pass data between classes. Recently I have read that callbacks are often times a better option than delegation. I am just wondering if I am doing this properly. Below is my code

```
class ViewControlleer: UIViewController {

let NS = NetworkServices()
let someNum = 10

  func getData(){
        NS.mainFunc(someNum, callback: { (newNum) -> Void in
            let newNumber = newNum*50
            print(newNumber)
        })
    }
}

class NetworkServices {


  func mainFunc(num: Int, callback: (Int)-> Void){
      let newNum = num*3
      callback(newNum)
  }


}
```

Using this pattern throughout my code would be good practice? Is it correct to say - "The `ViewController` class knows about the `NetworkServices` class but the reverse is not true"- ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your theory is spot on! Callbacks a great way to start depending on abstractions (the type signature) instead of concretions (the class that will implement the functionality). Here are a couple of ways you could clean up your Swift notation though:

**Trailing closures –** Swift will infer your callback type from the parameter type, so the following is equivalent:

```
func getData(){
    NS.mainFunc(someNum) { newNum in
        let newNumber = newNum*50
        print(newNumber)
    }
}
```

**Methods as functions –** This form lets you name things more clearly:

```
func getData(){
    NS.mainFunc(someNum, callback: myPrint)
}

func myPrint(newNum: Int) {
    let newNumber = newNum*50
    print(newNumber)
}
```

Comment: Could you please further explain what you mean when you say ..."a great way to start depending on abstractions instead of concretions"? Thanks

Comment: Yep! So here's a quick example of depending on concretions: `func mainFunc(num: Int, vc: ViewController) { vc.myPrint(num * 3) }`. This code is functionally equivalent to the code you posted in your Q. But now, the `NetworkServices` needs to know about the `ViewController` in order to do its job! In your version, however, we're using the type signature as the abstraction (a protocol would work too, but is overkill here). Now `NetworkServices` just knows that it will receive "something of a certain shape," which is all it needs to know!